# css special IE7 tag

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

```
*html .... (IE6)
html > body ....(IE7/FF)
```

`* html` is special tag for IE6. Does IE7 has something too? i need just some small css detail in IE7. Just for IE7 without FF.

Comment: It's more accurately known as a CSS selector hack. And those are frowned upon these days - include separate styles in conditional comments instead.

Comment: yes it is some sort of hack, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `*:first-child+html`, which you can prepend to `fieldset`. You *should* be using conditional comments though.

Your rule should look like..

`*:first-child+html fieldset { }`

Comment: @sen: what does your selector look like? It should work for IE7 and **only IE7**.

Comment: i read this howto: http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks so my selector looks like *:first-child+html fieldset {
    padding: 20px 0 0 10px;    
}

Comment: @sen: IE7 should recognize it. Are you sure that isn't being overridden by another more generic `fieldset {}` style?

Answer (score 2):

I've already used this answer to another question, but it applies here also:

> I have a solution that I use only when I have to, after I build my html & css valid and working in most browsers, I do the occasional hack with this amazing piece of javascript from Rafael Lima. http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
>
> It keeps my CSS & HTML valid and clean, I know it's not the ideal solution, using javascript to fix hacks, but as long as your code is originally as close as possible (silly IE just breaks things sometimes) then moving something a few px with javascript isn't as big of a deal as some people think. Plus for time/cost reasons is a quick & easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

`* html` is not a special tag for IE 6, it's rather an ugly hack exploiting a bug in the browser. You can use the conditional comments to include stylesheet for the various versions of IE:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i need just for one small tag, so i do not need whole css.

Answer (score 0):

This will proably answer your question: [CSS Hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/), but try to avoid them as much as possible :)